# How to add babel and polyfills to a RequireJs project?

Tags: babeljs, requirejs, internet-explorer-11, amd, polyfills

I am working on a legacy project which uses RequireJs to load and resolve all the dependencies. It works fine on modern browsers, but i need to add support for IE11.

I tried to use babel 7 with @babel/preset-env with following .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "corejs": 3,
            "targets": {
                "browsers" : ["ie>=11"]
            },
            "modules": false
        }]
    ],
    "compact": false
}
```

the import statements injected by the preset as following

```
import "core-js/modules/es.function.name.js";
```

cause error "import statements can't be used outside a module". Even when I use modules: "amd", then core-js is imported as

```
define(["core-js/modules/es.array.filter.js", "core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js", "core-js/modules/es.string.includes.js", "core-js/modules/es.function.name.js", "core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec.js", "core-js/modules/es.string.split.js", "core-js/modules/es.string.small.js", "core-js/modules/es.string.search.js"], function (_esArrayFilter, _esObjectToString, _esStringIncludes, _esFunctionName, _esRegexpExec, _esStringSplit, _esStringSmall, _esStringSearch) {
  "use strict";
//...
});
```

which throws error like "define is not defined in require.js".

2. When using useBuiltIns: "entry", and then including core-js as

```
require(["core-js", ../other modules], function(corejs, ...){
}
)
```

in the main.js file, it fails to correctly resolve the path of the files even though I have included the path to core-js in require.config.paths.

3. I tried @babel/runtime and @babel/plugin-transform-runtime but no luck there.

So my question is what would be the best way to add babel and the required polyfills in my RequireJs project so that it is compatible with IE 11?

Comment: If you want to use babel7 with requireJs, have you referred to this documentation, I think it should help you:[Babel Plugin for RequireJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-babel7?activeTab=readme).

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I found it bit difficult to understand the documentation. Based on the doc, I have added following
`requirejs.config({
 paths: {
  es6: 'node_modules/requirejs-babel7/es6',
  babel: 'node_modules/@babel/standalone/babel.min',
  'babel-plugin-transform-modules-requirejs-babel': 'node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-modules-requirejs-babel/index'
},
config: {
  es6: {
    extraPlugins: ['transform-async-to-generator', 'external-helpers'],
    presets: ['es2015'],
    targets: 'ie 11'
  }
})`
But,how to generate the babel-polyfills, babel-helpers files??